# Corona SDK performance. Animation or Sprite sheet

Tags: performance, sprite, coronasdk

General Corona SDK question, what would get better performance having a runtime event listener on enterFrame or a sprite sheet. So essentially what i have is:

```
local function animate(e)
    star.rotation = star.rotation +3;
end
Runtime:addEventListener ("enterFrame", animate);
return star;
```

Would this get better performance than having a sprite sheet that has the automation on loop. Both essentially go in a loop indefinitely (or until an action happens).

Answer (score 0):

It's really a trade off.  Your sprite is going to take up more memory, but it's probably faster to flip frames than it is to calculate the new angle and rotate the image.  But it's going to be a pretty trivial difference.